# Unable to load webpage using WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have recently taken up Android Development and I was looking to using the WebView display webpages. I picked up from the sample that was given on Google site and for some reason the emulator kept saying page was not available. I searched in StackOverflow and found links relating to WebViewClient. I tried that also but no luck there, I have checked multiple times about the manifest entry for internet permission and its there. As a test I ran the browser available within the emulator and sure enough my firewall popped up a question on whether to allow it access or not. The pop up never came to me when I was running it from program. The code that I have is what is there Google pages

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

I tried loading simple html directly using loadData and it worked fine. I am at loss as to what is happening and how this can be resolved. I would appreciate any help on this.

Adding the Android Manifest here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.hellowebview"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloWebView"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>     
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

To check if its just a WebView thingy, I tried accessing the internet using httpGet and httpResonse classes and got the same problem, the code was not able to connect to the given site. It failed stating the below

> 

```
05-10 00:37:53.191: WARN/System.err(294): java.net.UnknownHostException: feeds.feedburner.com
05-10 00:37:53.230: WARN/System.err(294):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
05-10 00:37:53.230: WARN/System.err(294):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
05-10 00:37:53.230: WARN/System.err(294):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
05-10 00:37:53.250: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
05-10 00:37:53.250: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-10 00:37:53.250: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-10 00:37:53.271: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
05-10 00:37:53.271: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-10 00:37:53.280: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-10 00:37:53.291: WARN/System.err(294):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-10 00:37:53.301: WARN/System.err(294):     at com.example.hellowebview.HelloWebView.onCreate(HelloWebView.java:43)
05-10 00:37:53.301: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-10 00:37:53.309: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-10 00:37:53.322: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-10 00:37:53.330: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-10 00:37:53.340: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-10 00:37:53.350: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 00:37:53.350: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 00:37:53.361: WARN/System.err(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-10 00:37:53.361: WARN/System.err(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 00:37:53.372: WARN/System.err(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-10 00:37:53.380: WARN/System.err(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-10 00:37:53.380: WARN/System.err(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-10 00:37:53.401: WARN/System.err(294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 00:37:56.773: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
05-10 00:37:58.083: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44fc9108 com.example.hellowebview/.HelloWebView}
05-10 00:38:06.300: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(58): pokeWakelock(5000)
05-10 00:38:06.651: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000077:03545404_00000004_00000000 [ 47 ipp] (67 ins) at [0x3724c8:0x3725d4] in 7266287 ns
05-10 00:38:06.720: INFO/ARMAssembler(58): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x371380:0x371548] in 1486222 ns
05-10 00:38:30.430: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(294): Shutting down VM
05-10 00:38:30.430: WARN/dalvikvm(294): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hellowebview/com.example.hellowebview.HelloWebView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at com.example.hellowebview.HelloWebView.onCreate(HelloWebView.java:51)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-10 00:38:30.752: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(294):     ... 11 more
```

Got it. For some reason the order in which the permission is set matters a lot. I changed the order of my permission setting in manifest file and it worked. Here's the modified manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hellowebview"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".HelloWebView"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>     
</application>
</manifest>
```

I am not sure what is the significance of this but would appreciate if anyone could elaborate.

Comment: did you add the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes I did, that was the first thing I did  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />. Gave it right after activity tag and within the applicaiton tag.

Comment: Ignore my answer, the solution worked only for a stand alone demo project I had. I integrated the same code into another application with two Activity where the browser was in the second activity and it failed to load the page while the internal browser is just loading fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. For some reason the order in which the permission is set matters a lot. I changed the order of my permission setting in manifest file and it worked. Here's the modified manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.hellowebview"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloWebView"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>     
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: It was not the order but the hierarchy of the tags. Permission should be direct child to manifest, not ordered inside the application tag.

Comment: NOTE: before <application tag you should use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` then it allow to browser internet.

Answer (score 5):

```
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);     
        WebSettings setting =mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return true;
        }
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Use this code .shouldOverrideUrlLoading() not use compulsary.use this code and please reply me this code work or not

Comment: I had that code in place. I moved the permission attribute in manifest file to be before the application tag and it started working fine. Thank You for the code.

Comment: Needed to use this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and then worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. I would make sure internet is working correctly on the emulator by browsing a few pages on the Android Browser. I have had problems before where the emulator would lose network access.

Comment: I did that, I used the emulator's browser to search through google and look at other webpage other than google also, and it worked fine.