# Android webview - webpage renders in a very broken way

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am trying to load this popular podcast in an Android WebView:

http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/entrepreneuronfirecom/entrepreneur-on-fire-tim-ferriss-other-incredible-entrepreneurs

And this is how I render it:

```
public class PodcastsActivity extends BaseActivity  
{    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setInitialScale(100);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/entrepreneuronfirecom/entrepreneur-on-fire-tim-ferriss-other-incredible-entrepreneurs");
```

And in my manifest I have the activity defined like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="PodcastsActivity"
        android:label="Podcasts" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```

But it renders like this:

[image]

Is there an extra setting that needs to be set? Or something I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you have looked at other answers. Some of the things you may try are:

1) From [webview not loading correctly in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425212/webview-not-loading-correctly-in-application) question, you may try and enable java script before loading the URL:

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

2) As per [Android webview not rendering html content correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174991/android-webview-not-rendering-html-content-correctly) question, if your target is higher than 2.3.3 try adding this in your manifest file.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

**Update**

3) Also check that you have following permission in `manifest` as direct child to `<manifest>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[Unable to load webpage using WebView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943591/unable-to-load-webpage-using-webview-in-android)

4) You can try [shouldOverrideUrlLoading()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5945130/1306419).

**Update 2**:

As you said that it displays correctly on your browser, there is another possibility of using the above method in case when a certain link is clicked within the app, it opens the default browser. I'm not sure if you would want this but it is a possibility. Something as follows:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

webview.loadUrl("http://www.stitcher.com/podcast/entrepreneuronfirecom/entrepreneur-on-fire-tim-ferriss-other-incredible-entrepreneurs");
```

Source: [WebView link click open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229494/webview-link-click-open-default-browser?lq=1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you - trying it now :) I was tinkering with enabling JS previously.

Comment: ohh. I'm sorry it didn't work. Which phone are you trying it on?

Comment: Right now I am trying on the simulator.

Comment: And I target sdk version 15 and added that hardwareAccelerated line

Comment: Just tested on a physical device. The same problem. It is a 2-year old phone. But OS is new: 4.0.4

Comment: Hmm..Interesting. I've updated the answer with few other references. See if any one of them is your case.

Comment: Thanks - I did #3. Now trying #4 from your suggestions

Comment: I also found this http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/09/android-webview-tutorial.html going to be trying it..but going to sleep soon. WIll try more tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik Does this load properly in a browser in the emulator?

Comment: this doesn't load properly either on a device, nor in the emulator when ran from the app. But when I just open a browser on my phone and run the url, then it does work fine.

Comment: You can use browser itself to open it, if you want to. See the updated answer.

Comment: this is interesting, but my requirement is that the user is kept on the app.

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the user on the app using this method? Or the browser takes over and the app is not being used? If the browser takes over, and the user gets taken outside of the app, I cannot use this approach.

Comment: Adding this line `webView.getSettings().useWideViewPort(true)`, worked for me.